# Grouping with drag and drop in WPF DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, grouping, controltemplate

I want to add a "drop" area to the existing WPF DataGrid, above the column headers.  In that area I want to allow the user to drop column headers that represent the columns to be grouped and to ungroup those columns by removing them from this area.  Xceed, SyncFusion, and other commercial grids provide this functionality but I need to do it myself.

My approach consisted of extracting the DataGrid's ControlTemplate, modifying it to my needs, and then creating a new control derived from DataGrid which defines this ControlTemplate in its generic.xaml.  For the most part this is working but there has to be a better way, is there?

I was looking for an approach that used attached properties but couldn't figure out how to insert the new "drop" area into the existing control's Visual Tree.

Any suggestions are welcomed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could write a Control that contains a DataGrid and overrides its ControlTemplate, or simply override it in the place you use it, if you only use it in one place.

However, encapsulating the DataGrid instead of inheriting from it wouldn't make that much of a difference.